# Force passing long file names to dos for command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have problem with following simple dos command:

```
FOR %%f IN (.\07_PROCEDURES\DataSources\*.sql) DO echo "%%f"
```

It does some action for every file with `sql` extension. Everything works fine, except long names. When directory contains files, with `sql_` extensions, they are picked up too. But this behavior depend on whether 8.3 files are [turned on or off](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007) on file system. If they are turned on (default choice on most computers) `sql_` are passed, because extension is cropped.

How to force `for` fetch long file names ? Thanks !

**P.S.** Do not offer powershell upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to examine the extension in the loop itself

```
for %%f in (*.sql) do  (
  if /i "%%~xf" EQU ".sql" echo %%f
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b .\*.sql ^| findstr /r .*\.sql$`) do @echo "%%f"
```

Comment: works fine, except one thing. it gives just filename, without path. but i need path. see updated code in question. figuring out, how i can join them...